# Android Studio 3.5 Error - Installation failed due to: ''pm install-create -r -t -S 1461173'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.5

I got this error when I tried to run my app. I installed flags -r -t but it doesn't solve the problem.
How do I solve this problem?

```
12/30 21:25:11: Launching 'app' on Nexus 6 API 22 Lollipop.
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: ''pm install-create -r -t -S 1461173' returns error 'Unknown failure: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.storage.StorageVolume[] android.os.storage.IMountService.getVolumeList()' on a null object reference''
```